# Chrome's devtools, device toolbar resolutions are weird

Tags: google-chrome, resolution, google-chrome-devtools

Im trying to make my website responsive to mobile devices.

I heard chrome's dev tools can simulate devices based on their resolutions. But  chrome has some weird resolutions.

**Iphone 7**

- `dev-tools:  375x667px`
- `officially: 750x1334px`

**Iphone 7 Plus**

- `dev-tools:  414x736px`
- `officially: 1080x1920px`

Even though they're different the simulator seems to be pretty accurate WHY?. This is seriously stressing me out as i don't if my max-width in my media queries are accurate on a genuine device or not.

Answer (score 4):

The resolution shown in the dev-tools is NOT **pixels** but **points**. Its used to ensure compatibility across different types of screens and resolutions (e.g. retina screen etc).

Modern mobile devices easely reach HD-resolution which would result in rendering the content just the same as on a desktop-browser. That's why the `Iphone 7/8 Plus` is shown as 414 in width. The phone is rendering the content and scaling it up to the actual screens resolution. This way you get a mobile view on full resolution.

[image]

You can read about the details here:
https://blog.fluidui.com/designing-for-mobile-101-pixels-points-and-resolutions/